# How to close the escape of the terminal in MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal

when I paste the website address to the terminal, the terminal will escape the character. 
eg: 
I paste the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=xxx` ,
in the terminal, it will convert into `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask\?title\=xxx`

How to close the escape in MacOS terminal?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the automatic escaping causing a problem?

Comment: What does “close the escape” mean?

Comment: Do you mean when you `drag` something into Terminal?

Comment: I copy the url in Chrome `Command + C` , When I paste into the Terminal (`Command + V`) , the url escaped. When I paste into the Sublime , the url is right

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to paste into Terminal without escapes: from the menu bar, choose Edit > Paste (default shortcut: <kbd>⌘V</kbd>).

[image: Edit > Paste menu item]

You only get escaping if you use Edit > Paste Escaped Text (default shortcut: <kbd>⌃⌘V</kbd>).

If your menu items have different keyboard shortcuts, you (or someone) has probably customized them using the Keyboard pane in System Preferences. It looks like this (although I haven't customized the Paste shortcuts):

[image: keyboard shortcut settings]

Comment: Additional Tip: If dragging something into Terminal hold `Shift` while dragging to leave unescaped.

Comment: My Terminal doesn't escape dragged-in text unless I hold control…

Comment: Interesting, does Shift have any effect?

Comment: Shift has no apparent effect for me on macOS 10.12.4.